# Как подключить .obj файл в QtCreator

Tags: c++, qtcreator

У меня есть скомпилированный из ассемблера .obj файл с функцией. Как мне подключить его к проекту в creator? Есть ли здесь вкладка настроек, как вкладка линкера в студии?(В студии подключается без проблем, только вот студия на моем компе не работает)

Comment: Obj файлы всегда подключаются списком, через параметры линкера. Компилятор создаёт набор obj-файлов, линкер их список связывает и оформляет в модуль (допустим исполнимый).

Comment: Если это сторонний .Obj файл, то попробуйте открыть qmake файл и найти строку переменную LIBS, и туда добавить свой obj файл как библиотеку: LIBS += файл.obj

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#objects Например: `OBJECTS += yourfile.obj` (В линуксах `OBJECTS += yourfile.o`)